# +/- 12v supply for AD8421

Tags: power-supply, voltage-doubler

I need +/- 12 Vdc power supply for [AD8421](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad8421.html#product-overview) from 5 Vdc. Can I use [LT3582](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3582.html#product-overview) (with output +/-12 Vdc; 85 mA) to supply the AD8421?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can, though be sure to check if the ripple is low enough for your needs. But why would you need a +-12 supply? Your DAC's reference is 5v.

Comment: I have 5 Vdc / 2.5A to supply 5 Vdc component. I so need +/- 12V dc to supply AD8421.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can supply the +/-12 without an MCU to set it up if you get the LT3582EUD-12. Assuming you can actually find any in stock. Otherwise, looks like you'd have to set it up with the \$\text{I}^{2}\text {C}\$ bus.

You could also consider a DC-DC converter module.

Getting close to the full 3nV/\$\sqrt{\text{Hz}}\$ performance out of the AD8421 may require a lot of care in layout and a multilayer board with nice ground planes when you have a switching regulator on board.

Comment: Thank you brother.